# Using multiple intents to pass information between classes

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am working on a To-Do application. The **MainActivity** displays the tasks created. When you click **Add Task**, it takes you to the **Create class**. Once you set the New Task up, you can click the **Save button** and it will be passed to the **MainActivity** via **Parcelable**.

If you click the newly displayed Task, it takes you to the **Display class**. From there you can choose to edit the activity, which will take you to **Edit class**.

**Flow of activity:**

*New Task Creation:* 
 Main class --> Create class --> Main class

*Editing Existing Task:*
Main class --> View class --> Edit Class --> Main class

**QUESTION**: If you are in **Edit**, how do you send back the information to update it in the MainActivity?

From the MainActivity I was using **startActivityForResult()**. Would I do a compounded startActivityForResult()?

Example:

Main class calls startAFR --> View class calls start AFR --> Edit --> Edit returns info to View --> View returns info to Main

Comment: One possible solution is to have a singleton that holds all the Tasks and have all your Activities interact with that singleton.

Answer (score 0):

You could use static fields in a utility class.

Comment: I would but I am prohibited from using static fields.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this problem was to use *Intents* and send the data back to the necessary activities. Similar to the **MainActivity**, I used **startActivityForResult()** to get the information I needed and passed it between the necessary classes. By using return codes in the Overridden **onActivityResult** method, I was able to perform whatever actions I needed. I'm not sure if this was the proper way to handle this but from my little knowledge of Android it's all I could generate.